# IOS7 image losing quality when rendering UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

let me explain first, when I take a picture with the camera, the picture is **1936x2592**, what I do next is crop the image to **320x320** and put it in a *UiImageView* , this works perfectly , no problem here

What I want to do is to render the *UiView* with the *UiImageView* inside and other elements like tags, labels etc with a **800x800** resolution without having the image losing quality

I want to do this to upload the picture to *facebook*.

The code for render the *UIView*:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(self.ImageView.bounds.size.width,self.ImageView.bounds.size.height), NO, 0.0f);

[self.View.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: show us code for rendering UIView.

Comment: SO is for specific problems, not vague ones like this. You've got to put in the research before someone else would be willing to help you. In either case, take a look at -[UIView renderInContext:]

Comment: I use renderInContext but my problem is that I lose quality when upload the picture, intelligent.

Comment: please post code how to render UIView?